# Запись отрицательного числа в двоичном виде

Tags: c#

Максимальный int в c#:

```
int x1 = 0b1111111111111111111111111111111;
```

Как получить такое же отрицательное число в Visual Studio?

Comment: `Int32.MinValue `?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, как записать отритательное число в двоичном виде.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но вроде у отрицательного числа первый бит в 1 выставлен. Попробуйте `int x1 = 1b1111111111111111111111111111111` , сам с телефона проверить не могу.

Comment: Ну, например, я посмотрел, с помощью команды Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(-2147483648,2)); Минимальный инт имеет вид 100000000000000000000000000000000 (31 нуль) - тоесть 32 разряда, как и положено, но при записи такого числа с помощью 0b... как в вопросе, студия ругается, да и максимальное положительное число представлено 31 цифарми.  Если менять 1 перед b, тоже ругается

Comment: `uint i = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000; Console.WriteLine((int)i);`

Comment: Спасибо большое! А вы не знаете, можно ли double в таком виде написать как-нибудь? Если да, то как?

Comment: никому в голову не придет руками побитово прописывать double в коде, это смысла не имеет никакого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uint i = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000; 
Console.WriteLine((int)i);
```